# Show state borders but not county borders on US Choropleth map

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I have some US county-level data and I want a choropleth map that does show state borders but not county borders. Following [this solution](https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-state-lines-to-county-level-geojson-based-choropleth/36269), I end up with this:

[image]

As you can see it seems the state borders are layered below the data. My attempt to solve this was to make a second choropleth with the state borders and a transparent colorscale, and layer that on top of the map with the data. First here's the borders-only figure:

```
state_borders = px.choropleth(df,
   geojson=counties,
   locations='fips',
   color='increase_12yr',
   color_continuous_scale=["rgba(1,1,1,0)" ,"rgba(1,0,0,0)"],
   range_color=(0, 350),
    center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    scope='usa',
    basemap_visible=False
)
state_borders.update_traces(marker_line_width=0, marker_opacity=1)
state_borders.update_geos(
showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="black"
state_borders.show()
)
```

[image]

So far so good, but when I try to add this as a trace to the original map, I end up with this:

[image]

Here is the full code minus my data specific stuff:

```
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

fig = px.choropleth(df,
   geojson=counties,
   locations='fips',
   color='increase_12yr',
   color_continuous_scale="Reds",
   range_color=(0, 350),
    center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    scope='usa',
    basemap_visible=False
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

state_borders = px.choropleth(df,
   geojson=counties,
   locations='fips',
   color='increase_12yr',
   color_continuous_scale=["rgba(1,1,1,0)" ,"rgba(1,0,0,0)"],
   range_color=(0, 350),
    center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    scope='usa',
    basemap_visible=False
)
state_borders.update_traces(marker_line_width=0, marker_opacity=1)
state_borders.update_geos(showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="black")

fig.add_trace(state_borders.data[0])

fig.show()
```

So anyone know how I can layer the state borders on top of my data?

Comment: From which csv/url you're making `df` ? Also, what is the column `increase_12yr` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's relevant to my problem, but it's some Zillow housing price data I've done some additional processing on and increase_12yr is just a float field.

Comment: Whether it's relevant or not to your problem, that makes your example non-[*reproducible*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) eitherway.

Comment: You can use the one they used in the link, `df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv", dtype={"fips": str})`, replacing increase_12yr with unemp

Answer (score 0):

Using a single [`choropleth`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.choropleth.html) map :

```
fig = px.choropleth(
    df, geojson=counties,
    locations="fips", color="unemp",
    color_continuous_scale="Reds",
    range_color=(0, 12),
    center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    scope="usa",
)

# ajdust the parameters/arguments if necessary
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0, "t":0, "l":0, "b":0})
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0, marker_opacity=0.7)
fig.update_geos(showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="black")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks okay only because that data is pretty uniformly filled out for all counties so the state borders appear pretty consistent. My actual data has more gaps in it, resulting in inconsistent visibility to the state borders. See the first version of the map i posted to see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but you can use the built-in argument `scope="usa"` in the `fig.update_geos` method.

```
fig.update_geos(
    visible=False, resolution=50, scope="usa",
    showcountries=True, countrycolor="Black",
    showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="Black", subunitwidth=1.5,
)
```

Fully reproducible example (with null regions included):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv", dtype={"fips": str})

max_value = df.unemp.max()
df.iloc[200:700, [1]] = None

fig = px.choropleth(df,
   geojson=counties,
   locations='fips',
   color='unemp',
   color_continuous_scale="Reds",
   range_color=(0, max_value),
    center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    scope='usa',
    basemap_visible=False
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0, marker_opacity=1)
fig.update_geos(
    visible=False, resolution=50, scope="usa",
    showcountries=True, countrycolor="Black",
    showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="Black", subunitwidth=1.5,
)
```

[image]